# Can I connect this LED Matrix to a ESP8266 Huzzah directly?

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266

[This tutorial](https://learn.adafruit.com/32x16-32x32-rgb-led-matrix/) for the 16x32 LED Matrix makes it sound like you have to use an Arduino Uno or Mega, but the tutorial was also written a few years ago.  I have a Huzzah ESP8266 (my project is about displaying information from the internet on the LED matrix) but I can't seem to get the  library to work with the Huzzah.

I am wondering if it would be possible to somehow hook up the LED matrix directly to the Huzzah. Can anyone make suggestions on this front?

Or do I have to basically make the Uno a slave to the Huzzah ESP8266? Need to figure out how to do that.

Thank you.

Comment: The library does not support ESPs, but in general you should be able to drive it with ESP if you have enough free pins. You might need a level shifter

Comment: So I would not be able to use the library, and would have to figure out another way to output to the matrix? I don't know where to start with that...might just make the Uno a slave if I can figure out how to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Huzzah is a great board but I don't think it is capable of driving a large led matrix by itself.  Adafruit also makes a led matrix feather wing which could enable the huzzah : https://www.adafruit.com/product/3090